# Highchart live with 2 graphs - shift trouble

Tags: php, highcharts, live

I use LIVE Highchart with 2 live graphs. The chart should display only 5 datapoints at on time. Therefore is the shift-argument

```
 var series1 = chart.series[0];
 shift1 = series1.data.length > 5;       
 series1.addPoint(point1, true, shift1);
```

So when point six arrives, point one is thrown away. But when i disable a series for a while ... and after enabling it again ... there was no shift.

http://www.abload.de/img/errorh5kko.jpeg

I reproduced it on jsfiddle for you

http://jsfiddle.net/yeDYr/1/

So both livegraphs no matter whether enabled or disabled should be shifted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug in Highcharts to me.  As a workaround, just `.show()` the series, then `hide()` it (if needed).  Highcharts seems to be able to do this without any visible flickering.

```
// the button action
$('#button1').click(function() {

    var point1 = Math.random() * 10;
    var point2 = Math.random() * 10;

    var series1 = chart.series[0];
    shift1 = series1.data.length > 5;

    isVisible = series1.visible;
    if (!isVisible) series1.show();
    series1.addPoint(point1, true, shift1);
    if (!isVisible) series1.hide();

    var series2 = chart.series[1];
    shift2 = series2.data.length > 5;

    isVisible = series2.visible;
    if (!isVisible) series2.show();
    series2.addPoint(point2, true, shift2);
    if (!isVisible) series2.hide();
});
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeDYr/2/).

Comment: yeah highchart-supports-team telled me that this is a bug ... https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1471